# How to iterate fields in qweb reports odoo?

Tags: reporting, qweb, odoo-13

How do you iterate fields in qweb reports? since I have two classes, I want customer_id to iterate base on the tree view created.

Models:

```
Class A:
    _name = 'module.a'

    module_id = fields.Many2one(string='sale', comodel_name='sale.order')
    customer_id = fields.Many2one('res.partner', string="Customer Name")

Class B:
    _inherit = 'sale.order'
    module_ids = fields.One2many(string="Module B",
                    comodel_name='module.a', inverse_name='module_id')
```

xml template:

```
   <template id="module_template" inherit_id="sale.sale_order_portal_content">
     <xpath expr="//div[2]/section[1]" position="before">
        <section class="mt-5">
            <h3 class="">Customer</h3>
            <div t-foreach="module_ids" t-as="line">
                <span t-esc="line.customer_id"/>
            </div>
        </section>
     </xpath>
  </template>
```

I try to do this but it won't iterate the customer_id in qweb report. The thing that only shows is the h3 - "Customer".

Note: That I need this to be One2Many and ManytoOne to create a tree view that adds a customer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

William Draper

Try to access this,

```
<div t-foreach="sale_order.module_ids" t-as="line">

    <span t-esc="line.customer_id"/>

</div>
```

You have access to the field in the report level with its `object` ['`sale_order`'].

Thanks

Comment: "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute module_ids"

Comment: Does not work also in sale.report_saleorder_document?

sale_order.module_ids

Comment: Error to render compiling AST
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'module_ids'
Template: sale.report_saleorder_document
Path: /t/t/t[2]/section/div/div[1]/div
Node: <div t-foreach="sale_order.module_ids" t-as="line">
                            <span data-oe-model="ir.ui.view" data-oe-id="1440" data-oe-field="arch" data-oe-xpath="/data/xpath/section/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/span[1]">Customer</span>
                            <span t-esc="line.customer_id.name"/>
                        </div>

Comment: Got it so sale_order = sale.sale_order_portal_content while doc = sale.report_saleorder_document

Comment: Thank you so much. 5 months left to deliver the project. Hard times due to COVID-19. Take Care.

Comment: @William is your issue is solved? after changing the object field access to 'sale_order'?